# Uniquely identify a Windows Phone installation

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, uniqueidentifier, windows-live-id

I am building a web/mobile social service application for Windows Phone.

As a final goal, I will want my users to have an account at my online service site, but as an application provides a Twitter/Facebook integrated functionality, I don't want to bother client with registering at my site first from the beginning.

But I need to create an account for all user requests to be stored at on the web "under the hood".

What is the best way to uniquely identify an application instance on WP7.5? Is there a unique application installation ID I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get unique ID of **device** by using [DeviceExtendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties) as described in this question: [What is the right way to get Unique Identifier of windows phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524435/what-is-the-right-way-to-get-unique-identifier-of-windows-phone-7)

**UPDATE**

With help of [UserExtendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties.aspx) you can get unique ID of **user** [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520387/windows-phone-7-userextendedproperties/4520528#4520528). This way you will get ANID ([anonymous identifier](http://adventuresinsoftware.com/blog/?p=569)) based on Live ID. Don't forget to include `ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER` in your `WMAppManifest.xml`.

Comment: Problem with this is that it persists if the user gets their device stolen/sold

Comment: I'm about to be facing a similar issue so excuse me for asking questions - but a user could have multiple windows phones, so just the ANID wouldn't work. I guess a solution could be to concatenate them in a way like <anid><non-base64 character><unique-identifier> so you could chop them up later. One last thing though DeviceUniqueID is deprecated, and UserExtendedProperties says to only use with the Advertising SDK.

Comment: @willmel - actually `DeviceUniqueID` is the only not deprecated property on DeviceExtendedProperties page.

Comment: Thanks Pol. But since on MSDN page it says: "The UserExtendedProperties API should only be used by applications that use the Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone." I guess I won't risk using it for other purposes. I may not pass the marketplace approval for violating this I guess.